# Entity Framework fetching slowly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've got a database of around a million record. I'm doing a query using entity framework and the logging tell me that the actual execution time is 60ms. I'dont understand why but the complete execution time is 3 sec... ( BeforeToList + AfterToList). Only 10 rows are fetched...

3 Seconds is very slow...

Here is the code:

```
    public IEnumerable<Event> GetEvents(IEnumerable<int> idList)
    {
        using (var db = new context())
        {
            db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var query = db.Event.Where(o => idList.Contains(o.EventId));
            var elapsedMs1 = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            watch.Stop();
            watch.Reset();
            watch.Start();

            var query2 = query.ToList();
            watch.Stop();
            var elapsedMs2 = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            Console.WriteLine("data.BeforeToList:" + elapsedMs1 + " --- AfterToList:" + elapsedMs2);
            return query2;
        }
    }
```

And here is the output:

```
Test Name:  IsGetEventsReturn10Result
Test Outcome:   Passed
Result StandardOutput:  

data.BeforeToList:1148 --- AfterToList:2883


Debug Trace:
Opened connection at 2015-03-13 21:15:40 -04:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[EventId] AS [EventId], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[UrlReference] AS [UrlReference], 
    [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Extent1].[TimezoneId] AS [TimezoneId], 
    [Extent1].[Image1Id] AS [Image1Id], 
    [Extent1].[Image2Id] AS [Image2Id], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
    [Extent1].[UpdatedOn] AS [UpdatedOn], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent1].[SourceId] AS [SourceId], 
    [Extent1].[Source] AS [Source], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [Extent1].[Price] AS [Price], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[DescriptionUrl] AS [DescriptionUrl]
    FROM [dbo].[Event] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[EventId] IN (366623, 366622, 366621, 366620, 366619, 366618, 366617, 366616, 366615, 366614)


-- Executing at 2015-03-13 21:15:41 -04:00

-- Completed in 60 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 2015-03-13 21:15:41 -04:00
```

Comment: How many records did you fetch? What is your database design?? I.E. Table structure I suggest to run the SQL in database and see how much time it takes, if possible, try to capture an execution plan

Comment: Due to lazy loading, the query isn't probably executed until you call `query.ToList()`

Comment: @Mr.香港人 Only 10 row fetched... 
@JNYRanger I understand that but it still 1 sec before the `ToList()` and 2 sec for the `ToList()` doesn't make any sense...

Comment: then how much time it takes to run in the database??

Comment: `-- Completed in 60 ms with result: SqlDataReader`

Comment: That's not entirely unsurprising, since you're disposing the context on each call to GetEvents.

Comment: @TiesonT. ok but the dispose is done after the timer no?

Comment: The most time-intensive step in EF is building the DbContext, which, since you dispose it each time, means you have to do it each time you call the method.

Comment: @TiesonT. The problem is that inside the `using` I'm declaring 2 timers, and the timers show only for 1 call to `GetEvents`. I will keep in mind your comment for when I will have multiple call , but first, right now, I only have one and a very slow one :(

Comment: If you call GetEvents twice in the same run of program, is the second one significantly faster?  DbContext takes a little while to compile the first time you use it, but that cost is only paid the first time one is created. That could account for the slow first measurement, especially since it shouldn't actually perform the query until ToList is called.

Comment: a lot faster indeed! first time 3 sec, second time 37ms, third time 33ms

Comment: also, queries are compiled on the EF side the first time they are executed, and that is also cached.  that should be pretty quick for simple queries like yours, certainly not in the thousands of ms.  So that's a bit of a mystery still.

Comment: @jlew well you were right, I will have to figure a way to simulate the first call to the context or something like that since I cannot keep the context open infinitely and I can't let my user getting a 3sec each time they want to use the db

Comment: You don't need to keep the context open.  Tieson is incorrect that constructing it each time is expensive.  only the first construction is expensive, after that everything important is cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comments of jlew, I did find a good article that explain the difference between the first call (cold query) and the others (warm query).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/hh949853.aspx

To help the cold query be faster, I did pre-generated the view using The Entity Framework Power Tools.

No code change was needed.